i use tanstack react query and in this i use useInfiniteQuery now i want to do invalidatequery for particuler page how to do this?
enter image description here
When you invalidate queries, you essentially tell your caching mechanism to refresh the data it has stored. However, if you invalidate all queries upon update, it triggers unnecessary API calls for all pages. To avoid this, you can modify your invalidation process to target only the page that was updated. This can be achieved by passing the page number or a unique identifier associated with the updated page to the invalidation function. By doing so, you ensure that only the specific page's data is refreshed, optimizing performance and reducing unnecessary API calls.
  const {
    data: timelineData,
    fetchNextPage,
    hasNextPage,
  } = useInfiniteQuery(
    {
      queryKey: [
        `timeline-${entity_id}-${recordId}-${timelineViewId}`,
        entity_id.toString(),
        recordId.toString(),
        timelineViewId.toString(),
        JSON.stringify(filterData),
        currentEntity?.entity_uuid &&
          selectedView?.timeline?.[currentEntity?.entity_uuid]?.searchText,
      ],
      queryFn: fetchTimeline,
      initialPageParam: 0,
      getNextPageParam: (lastPage) => {
        return lastPage?.[lastPage?.length - 1]?.offset_;
      },
      refetchInterval: TIMELINE_INTERVAL_TIME,
    },
    queryClient
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isTimelineLoaded) {
      queryClient.invalidateQueries({
        queryKey: [
          `timeline-${entity_id}-${recordId}-${timelineViewId}`,
          entity_id.toString(),
          recordId.toString(),
          timelineViewId.toString(),
          JSON.stringify(filterData),
          currentEntity?.entity_uuid &&
            selectedView?.timeline?.[currentEntity?.entity_uuid]?.searchText,
        ],
      });
    }
  }, [isTimelineLoaded]);

